# Banners are overlapping in detail page

Tags: visualforce, page-layout

I want to show 2 banners on Account detail page. I have created visulforce page for this and have added this page to page layout section.
Below is the visualforce code.

```
<apex:outputPanel layout="block" rendered="{!if(Account.Membership_Status_Formula__c!='Rescinded'&&isnull(Account.Trustee__c)&&!isnull(Account.Committee_Membership_List__c)&&isnull(Account.SOL_Manager__c),true,false)}">            
        <apex:outputpanel layout="block" style="background-color:yellow;color:black;width:100%;height:20px;float:left;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;padding-top:2px;" >
            <apex:outputText value="Trustee Member" />
        </apex:outputpanel>       
    </apex:outputpanel>


    <apex:outputPanel layout="block" rendered="{!if(!isnull(Account.RM_Tracking__c),true,false)}">            
        <apex:outputpanel layout="block" style="background-color:orange;color:black;width:100%;height:20px;float:left;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;padding-top:4px;" >
            <apex:outputText value="Test Banner" />
        </apex:outputpanel>       
    </apex:outputpanel>
```

But I can't see "Test Banner" on account record detail page.

Please suggest on this.

Comment: btw, rendered="{!!isnull(Account.RM_Tracking__c}" is good for rendering instead of if condition

Answer (score 0):

In the Test Banner rendering condition, instead of using `if` condition

```
rendered="{!if(!isnull(Account.RM_Tracking__c),true,false)}">
```

Use, `rendered="{!NOT(isnull(Account.RM_Tracking__c))}">`

Which will return same result.

Test Banner will not display if above condition is not met.